# Exclude results from Elasticsearch / Kibana based on aggregation value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

Is it possible to exclude results based on the outcome of an aggregation?

In other words, I have aggregated on a Term and a whole bunch of results appear in a data table ordered in descending order by the count.  Is it possible to configure kibana / elasticsearch to exclude results where count is 1 or less.  (Where count is an aggregation).

I realise I can export the raw data from the data table visualization and delete those records manually through a text editor or excel.  But I am trying to convince my organization that elasticsearch is a cool new thing and this is one of their 1st requirements...

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the result from the search by applying a filter here a sample that can be helpfull.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
          "range": {
        "Your_term": {
          "gte": 1
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your input.  I realise I can filter on the source data, but the trouble is I want to filter on the aggregation.  In my example above, the aggregation is named count.  As far as I can tell, your method above does not allow me to filter on aggregations.  Is that right?  Thanks

Comment: Can you please put you aggs query so that i can be more relevant to your query. @asdf01